# Importing a component renders a blank page with TypeError: Cannot set property 'components' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

There is a Vue component `DisplayContent`,

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
import Home from "@/components/Home.vue";

@Component({
  components: {
    Home
  }
})
export default class DisplayContent extends Vue {}
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

And this `Home` component is like,

```
<template>
  <div id="content-container">
    <v-container>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium,
      voluptates. Blanditiis neque dolore adipisci? Ad temporibus dolorum nihil
      nam necessitatibus ratione, atque sint. At nostrum quos quas odit
      recusandae sunt.
    </v-container>
  </div></template
>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
export default class Home extends Vue {}
</script>

<style>
#content-container {
  padding-top: 3%;
}
</style>
```

I am loading the 'Display' component inside the main App.vue and it renders a blank page with a console error - `TypeError: Cannot set property 'components' of undefined`

Interestingly though, if I remove `v-component` from `Home` component, then it loads fine without any error -

```
<template>
  <div id="content-container">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium,
      voluptates. Blanditiis neque dolore adipisci? Ad temporibus dolorum nihil
      nam necessitatibus ratione, atque sint. At nostrum quos quas odit
      recusandae sunt.
  </div></template
>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
export default class Home extends Vue {}
</script>

<style>
#content-container {
  padding-top: 3%;
}
</style>
```

Also if I copy the `Home` component (along with `v-container`) inside the `Display` component, it renders everything properly.

Why is it that having `v-container` inside `Home` doesn't load anything and gives error?

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else faces this, I solved this by adding an empty @Component decorator to Home.vue - https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7804#issuecomment-702056619